# Convexity of rational functions between poles

Tags: convex-analysis, rational-functions

#### Problem statement

Consider the following rational function:
$$ f(x) = -\frac{(x-a)(x-d)}{(x-b)(x-c)(x-e)} $$
where $a < b < c < d < e$.

I would like to prove that $f$ is convex on $(b,c)$.

---

#### Example

Here is an illustration of such a function with $(a,b,c,d,e) = (1,2,3,4,5)$.
[image: Example of such a function]

Here is an interactive plot to visualize such a function made with geogebra:

https://www.geogebra.org/m/fcs8rbcr

---

#### What I tried

- I tried to calculate the second derivative which is quite complex.
- I tried to think in terms of variations of the function, we know its roots, its poles and its sign.

Perhaps there is a quick solution to such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of $f$ is
$$
 f(x) = \frac{B}{x-b} + \frac{C}{x-c} + \frac{E}{x-e}
$$
with
$$
 B = - \frac{(b-c)(b-d)}{(b-a)(b-e)} > 0\\
 C = - \frac{(c-a)(c-d)}{(c-b)(c-e)} < 0\\
 E = - \frac{(e-a)(e-d)}{(e-b)(e-c)} < 0
$$
and on $(b, c)$ is $1/(x-b)$ convex, whereas $1/(x-c)$ and $1/(x-e)$ are concave.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Tasty: You are welcome. I have rewritten it a bit to make it easier to recognise where the factors come from.